# I need a proper design for the table code. I have 3 tables

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,booktabs}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}   
 % Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
    % \usepackage{multirow}
    \begin{table}[]
    \begin{tabular}{clccc}
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Variations}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Parameters}}                             & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}DE based\\  PID\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}TLBO based \\ 2-dof PID\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}GWO based\\ 3-dof PID\end{tabular}} \\
    \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Area 1}}        & \textbf{Settling time}                                              & 12.3404                                                          & 10.562                                                                   & 6.741                                                                  \\
                                            & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Peak \\ Undershoot\end{tabular}} & -0.0284                                                          & -0.00853                                                                 & -0.00156                                                               \\
                                            & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Peak\\ Overshoot\end{tabular}}   & 0.0026                                                           & 0.000576                                                                 & 0.000255                                                               \\
    \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Area 2}}        & \textbf{Settling time}                                              & 8.2911                                                           & 11.4377                                                                  & 5.756                                                                  \\
                                            & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Peak \\ Undershoot\end{tabular}} & -0.024                                                           & -0.000869                                                                & -0.000639                                                              \\
                                            & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Peak\\ Overshoot\end{tabular}}   & 0.0068                                                           & 0.0054                                                                   & 0.00354                                                                \\
    \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Tie-Line}}      & \textbf{Settling time}                                              & 14.0627                                                          & 10.0456                                                                  & 5.658                                                                  \\
                                            & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Peak \\ Undershoot\end{tabular}} & -0.0046                                                          & -0.0028                                                                  & -0.00021                                                               \\
                                            & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Peak\\ Overshoot\end{tabular}}   & 0.00023                                                          & 0.00021                                                                  & 0.00015                                                               
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

This is what I'm required to get.

[image: table]

Comment: please extend your code snippet to complete small compilable document. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Please fine tune the code to look clean in pdf

Comment: i ask you to provide complete small document ..., from question is clear, what you like to obtain. to see, how is important complete document, see my answer ...

Answer (score 7):

**edit:**

after providing mwe it is clear now, that you have two column document and that probably you like to have table in one column. in this case the first example is not useful, the second one id now renewed.

**first example:** anticipated standard `article` document class:

[image]

a table code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{table}[htb]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{table-format=2.6}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                >{\bfseries}c
                >{\bfseries}l
                SSS}
    \toprule
\thead[l]{Variations} 
    &   \thead{Parameters} 
        &   {\thead{DE based\\  PID}} 
            &   {\thead{TLBO based \\ 2-dof PID}} 
                &    {\thead{GWO based\\ 3-dof PID}}                        \\
    \midrule
Area 1        
    & Settling time     &   12.3404     &   10.562      &   6.741       \\
    & Peak Undershoot   &   -0.0284     &   -0.00853    &  -0.00156     \\
    & Peak Overshoot    &    0.0026     &    0.000576   & 0.000255      \\
    \addlinespace
Area 2
    & Settling time     &    8.2911     &   11.4377     &    5.756      \\
    & Peak Undershoot   &   -0.024      &   -0.000869   &   -0.000639   \\
    & Peak Overshoot    &    0.0068     &    0.0054     & 0.00354       \\
    \addlinespace
Tie-Line
    & Settling time     &   14.0627     &   10.0456     &    5.658      \\
    & Peak Undershoot   &   -0.0046     &   -0.0028     &   -0.00021    \\
    & Peak Overshoot    &    0.00023    & 0.00021       & 0.00015       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**second example:**
considered is your edit of the question:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}% mathtools load amsmath, amsymb contain amstex too
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{%array, 
            booktabs,           % loaded by makecell
            makecell,           % added
            multirow}           % not used in this mwe
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum}             % added for dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{table}[htb]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{table-format=2.6}
\small
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                l
                SSS}
    \toprule
\thead{Parameters}
    &   {\thead{DE based\\  PID}}
        &   {\thead{TLBO based \\ 2-dof PID}}
            &    {\thead{GWO based\\ 3-dof PID}}                \\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\textbf{Area 1}}                             \\
Settling time     &   12.3404     &   10.562      &   6.741     \\
Peak Undershoot   &   -0.0284     &   -0.00853    &  -0.00156   \\
Peak Overshoot    &    0.0026     &    0.000576   & 0.000255    \\
    \addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\textbf{Area 2}}                             \\
Settling time     &    8.2911     &   11.4377     &    5.756    \\
Peak Undershoot   &   -0.024      &   -0.000869   &   -0.000639 \\
Peak Overshoot    &    0.0068     &    0.0054     & 0.00354     \\
    \addlinespace
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\textbf{Tie-Line}}                           \\
Settling time     &   14.0627     &   10.0456     &    5.658    \\
Peak Undershoot   &   -0.0046     &   -0.0028     &   -0.00021  \\
Peak Overshoot    &    0.00023    &    0.00021    & 0.00015     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

as you can see, the table is redesigned that it can be fit in one column. in this i suggest to "transform" first column to rows (see mwe above). in above mwe is used:

- for column headers macro `thead` from the package `\makecell`
- for numbers align in the last three columns `S` column type from the package `siunitx` (it also support writing of the SI units)
- macro `@\extracolsep{\fill}}`, which determine distances between columns. their size is foirst set to zero, and then by it calculated so, that table wodth is equal to column width.

about tables design: it is worth to give a look to ["wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten"](https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/) and many nice design provided here on the site.

Comment: are you asking about which package i am using @zarko ?

Comment: @AdityaNanda, yes, i ask you this already twice :-). people here like to know document class, which you use, all packages and settings relevant to page layout (that we see how wide a table can be, which font you use etc) and packages which relevant to table settings. all other from your document we not need. table in my answer is written in my tables test-bed, which can significantly differ from your document.

Comment: ok i got you. i am writing for IEEE transaction. I can install any package.  \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

Comment: when i try to use \makecell package there is no error showing. and all just stay there as it is

Comment: @AdityaNanda, now you have two complete examples. hopefully they will help you at your tables design.

Comment: can you please again edit the code without makecell or lipsum package. because when i try to run the code, nothing changes. i installed both the packages but no results. no error or anything. it will be ok if you can write it in simple box format and it will be ok if it can be wriiten in table*. thank you

Comment: answer is what it is. i will not change anything since it work perfect. if you not liked it, than please wait on answer of someone else. `lipsum` (it is only for demonstrate text and in real document should not be used) you can delete yourself (in your test, not in answer).  it is very unclear what you mean with "nothing changes".